# Backup a bootable partition with rsync

Tags: macos, backup, rsync

I use rsync to create a backup of my boot partition (Mavericks).
Everything is OK (during the backup) but the backup partition does not boot (it seems to loop infinitely).

I think I used the correct arguments to rsync, included the following
options:
`--hfs-compression` and `--protect-decmpfs`

Any ideas?

(of course, I used bless to make it bootable)

Answer (score 2):

Repair the permissions has allowed to solve the problem. The backup partition is now booting without any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use CarbonCopyCloner (http://www.bombich.com) it's a masterpiece by Mr. Bombich. It uses rsync as the backup engine and takes care of all the nitty gritty re blessing, recovery partitions, etc. etc. You can do full partitions or just selected folders and files. All in a very Mac-like way. You can't go wrong (I know what this looks like, but I am not associated with Bombich in any way, just been saved by CCC many many times).

Comment: I'am sorry but I am aware of CCC, SuperDuper etc ... but I really want to use Terminal commands (rsync ...) to do my backup.

Comment: you should probably still take a look at Bombich's site, in the support area/documentation there are loads of info on how the boot/blessing/ownership details fit into the building of bootable copies.

Comment: There are many interesting informations at Bombich' site. Thanks for the suggestion